# why the result of strlen() out of my expection?

Tags: c

The function strlen() counts the number of characters in a string up to NUL and it doesn't contain
NUL.In ASCII,NUl is equal to '\0'.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char a[]="abc";
    char b[]="abcd'\0'def";
    printf("%d\n%d",strlen(a),strlen(b));
    return 0;
}
```

The result is 3 and **5**.
THe second result is in contradiction with the first result.
Thus ,I try to find how to implement strlen().

```
int strlen(char a[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++);
    return i;
}
```

Based on this code ,I can understand the first result,but really can't understand the second one.
Why is the sceond result not 4 but 5?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the single quotes only for a char literal.

Comment: Print b[] to the console... You'll see that the (left) apostrophe is the mysterious 5th character... Remove the \0 and you'll see that there are two apostrophes...

Comment: a, b, c, d, single quotation mark, null character, single quotation mark, d, e, f

Comment: Return type of `strlen` is `size_t. The correct format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`, not `%d`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting 5 because you have wrapped the `NUL` character in single quotes, the value 5 is the length of the string "abcd'".

If you change the second example to `"abcd\0ef"` (no single quotes), you get a value of 4.

Answer (score 1):

```
char b[]="abcd'\0'def";
```

the array elements are

```
[a][b][c][d]['][0]['][d][e][f][0]
```

so the lenthth of the string before first `[0]` is 5 as it contains `'` character as well.

Answer (score 1):

> In ASCII, NUL is equal to '\0'.

NUL, and the null character, are equal to `'\0'`, that is correct. But what you are looking here is a *character literal* (one character, `\0`, *enclosed in single quotes*). Within a string literal, those single quotes are not needed, and will indeed be interpreted as characters of their own.

So this...

```
char a[]="abc";
char b[]="abcd'\0'def";
```

...is equivalent to:

```
char a[]= { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' };
char b[]= { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '\'', '\0', '\'', 'd', 'e', 'f', '\0' };
```

Your *intention* for `b` was this:

```
char b[]="abcd\0def";
```